# Why jest.fn() can be assigned to any function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm confused how jest.fn() works in Typescript. For example

```
class MyClass {
  myFunction() {
    return 'hello'
  }
}

let myClass = new MyClass()
myClass.myFunction = jest.fn()
```

From my understanding, myClass.myFunction has a type of '() => string' but jest.fn() returns a 'Mock'. I notice that 'Mock' is in fact extends 'Function' but Function is less specific then () => string so how could this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the types from `@types/jest`](https://unpkg.com/browse/@types/jest@27.5.0/index.d.ts), it extends function but with a specific call signature:

```
interface Mock<T = any, Y extends any[] = any>
  extends Function, MockInstance<T, Y> {
    new (...args: Y): T;
    (...args: Y): T; // <--
}
```

`fn()` returns just `Mock` and because the default return type (`T`) is `any`, this is allowed.

`fn` can be called with type arguments to specify the return type explicitly or, more conveniently, the types can be inferred from the implementation function:

```
function fn<T, Y extends any[]>(implementation?: (...args: Y) => T): Mock<T, Y>;
```

Example:

```
// Identifies wrong return type (Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string')
myClass.myFunction = jest.fn(() => { })

// Correct return type
myClass.myFunction = jest.fn(() => '')
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAEBcGcFoEsDmA7A9gJwKagD6gFICu0koAZhqIppJPMoqJABbaQCeADptKPaNADGqbgFgAUPAC2nDKQDkULj2AArHpHkBuCRMEAbAIbReAWXYBhIydABvCaFBT2AMULJBdVMgAUASjsHR1AsSEJ0ZFB5Vn19VHkggF8JZPEJfRonS2teAF5QZEwAd1BzK2NofwkQUABJABNMZDoyeB5QIvRvRlDwyI4xcWdykwA6ZzcPL0j89RJRsl9-UFyAPjtQRL9dcRqLDCxPEJo+pmUJYZzx13dPeG8V0DnIBaWAtaj5bd2wU1RBADWHXgLFAAANDMh2GDjmEImdBpcKtdJncHrMNK8quIgA)

---

If the types from the jest packages themselves are used, then `jest.fn()` without anything else will also yield an error, because it returns a `Mock<UnknownFunction>`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgKwKYGd4F84DMoQhwDkAAmpgPQDmANhAEYCGt6xAsAFBcDGtT6dHACyATwDC-QYi5w4IUQDEArgDseMYBFUAKAJQzOcuVFQxlUVSQAWqWvQ5G4WLi+6daZ+RKlCAvHCqqADuIj4C6PpclJRwKuqa2nBqANaqEMGqXAqSEQB0CvEaWlYBFDB5uLp60bEAkgAmqKqauMAYcMEEqtRwpuaWcDCiYKjZ4YIFSmrFSWUYFVU6+nB+AHyIzjXuMXDi0KYafWYWVsOj47mThTOJpSgLlbor6yTE20A)

Comment: In case we are calling just jest.fn() without passing in any implementation, doesn't this part, (...args: Y): T, just means that Mock has a function that will return any? But the Mock itself still just has the type of Function, MockInstance<any, any>?

Comment: @hikky36: It defines the call signature and the function return type, refining the generic `Function` type. The `MockInstance` part just provides more additional members. Updated the answer by the way because there is a mismatch in behavior depending on where the types come from.